# Windows Git pre-commit check file signature

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm trying to ensure that a specific file is signed properly before allowing the file to be commited.  I'm using powershell to do this, but this isn't a powershell issue.  Here's the command I'm using to do the check:

```
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command "If ((Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\test.ps1).Status -ne 'Valid') { Exit 1 }"
```

Note: I've tried with variation of the following powershell switches:

```
-NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile
```

At first, the appeared to be that the exit code is lost and is always 0.  After further investigation, it appears that this command doesn't even run.  For example, here's a test command:

```
/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -Command "Get-Location | Out-File C:\Temp\test.txt"
```

This *test* command runs fine when executed from the GitBash shell; the test.txt file is created.  When in the pre-commit hook file, it fails to create the test.txt file; this is technically TortoiseGit running this part.

**Question:**  On windows, how do I ensure that a specific file is signed properly before allowing the file to be commited?  Is there a way to have the `gpg` command use the windows cert store for validation of a signature?

I feel like this is a TortoiseGit issue, but wanted to bounce this on you all.  I’ve submitted an issue:
https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2143

Comment: Does your git host allow you to have hooks? You could also consider rejecting pushes with bad signatures

Comment: GitLab CE, so no pre-receive hooks. I was just trying to set this up because I keep forgetting to sign it before I commit.